# Laravel database query read not using get

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, fetch

I have spent 1 hour looking for this on google but I didnt have luck

This is my first time with Laravel. I'm must trying a basic example with databases. First my old code using normal php:

```
echo "<table border=1>";
$q="SELECT * from USERS"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($q);
while(($o = $result->fetch_object()))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$o->ID</td><td>$o->Name</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Now I'm trying the same in laravel

```
$query=DB::Table("users")->select("*");
```

I know that i can use

```
$allrows=$query->get();
```

This one gets all results in an array, but if you have 2 millions of users it is a big problem.

And this one returns the first row

```
$Firstrow=$query->first();
```

I just want to get rows one by one, something like

```
$query=DB::Table("users")->select("*");

while($o=$query->next())
    {   
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$o->ID</td><td>$o->Name</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Maybe I'm wrong since I'm new to Laravel but this use less memory since only one active.

PD: I have seen pagination in laravel, but I just want the old method row by row... if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Last probably, Laravel Framework 7.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this you can use the `cursor()` method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->cursor();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->id;
}
```

If you're passing `$users` to a blade file then you could have the following

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <td>{{ $user->ID }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->Name }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cursor method instead of get() function. as the cursor method allows you to iterate through your database records using a cursor, which will only execute a single query.

```
foreach (Flight::where('foo', 'bar')->cursor() as $flight) {
    //
}
```

ref link:- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Comment: thanks this is what i was looking for, but the selected one was before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chunks method provided by eloquent. Read more about it here https://laraveldaily.com/process-big-db-table-with-chunk-method/

```
DB::table('users')->chunk(100, function($users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, chunks are an option but I was looking for the way that i did it in mysql.

Comment: Okay, no problem.